# What does a function prototype mean with an ampersand in it? 

Tags: c++, function, prototype, ampersand

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the '&' operator do in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943276/what-does-the-operator-do-in-c)

In my CS class today the teacher showed us some examples of functions and templates and some of the prototypes for functions had ampersands in the list of parameters like this:

```
void exchange( T & x, T & y ) ; // prototype
```

what does that mean? What should I use it for?

Comment: If this was in class, you should have asked your professor! Never be afraid to ask questions.

Comment: If you were shown a prototype like that in class, the purpose of the lecture was probably to *introduce* ampersands. Pay closer attention next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the **&** is for **reference**. In short that's something like a **pointer, that can't be NULL**. Wikipedia has something on this topic [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29).

References are **cheap** when they are used in function/method calls, since the object doesn't need to be copied in your function call. You still have the same syntax as if you had with a copied object. With pointers you would need to handle the special case, that the pointer is **NULL**.

That is a usual reason to use them. If I guess right and **exchange** means something like **swap the tow objects x and y**, the the cost of the function call is directly related to the cost of coping the object, so saving some copies may be a relevant optimization.

Comment: It's more than a pointer that can't be NULL, since a reference cannot be reseated

Answer (score 1):

The `&` means 'reference to' - `x` is a reference to a `T`, not a copy.