# What does & in C++ function arguments list mean?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between pointer variable and reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)
>   [What does a function prototype mean with an ampersand in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488894/what-does-a-function-prototype-mean-with-an-ampersand-in-it)

In my understanding,

```
void bar(int &x) { ... }
```

Seem to mean pass `x` by reference. But in C++, there are pointers etc already. So what difference is there to

```
void bar(int *x) { ... }
// then call by
bar(&x);
```

Apart from the fact that it's longer... I also noticed if I use the 2nd method, I need to use `->` as opposed to `.` if I pass in a `struct`... why?

Comment: Lots of dupes. It is a reference, yes.

Comment: i seems you may have to read a bit about C++ , googling just about "c++ references" will lead you to a lot of excellent documentation and explanation of the concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason Stroustrup gives for introducing references to C++ is operator overloading.

http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#pointers-and-references

In your example function `bar`, it is no big deal whether the user has to call it as `bar(&x)` (because it takes a pointer), or can call it with `bar(x)` (because it takes a reference). At least, C programmers think it isn't.

However, when operator overloading was added to C++, Stroustrup considered that using overloaded operators with pointers is very inelegant ("ugly" in his words).

References have some advantages in functionality over pointers, such as the fact that a temporary object can be bound to a const reference, but you can't apply the `&` operator to it. So a pass-by-const-reference function sometimes saves the caller a line of code (to create a variable) compared with its pass-by-pointer-to-const equivalent.

For this reason, one possible convention is to accept a pointer when your function plans to store the address somewhere for future use after it returns, and a reference when it doesn't. It doesn't prevent all possible ways of creating a dangling pointer/reference, but it catches a big one. It does have unfortunate consequences when writing functional-style code, though, so it's not for everyone.

> I also noticed if I use the 2nd method, I need to use -> as opposed to
>   . if I pass in a struct... why?

It's just the syntax inherited from C. `.` to access a member of a struct, `->` to access a member via a pointer-to-struct. In C you can *only* use `->` with a pointer on the LHS, and you can *never* use `.` with a pointer on the LHS. So there's no strict need for different symbols, it just helps make code more readable to have reminders. For example, if the same symbol `.` was used for both then `(*ptr).member` would mean the same thing as `ptr.member`, which would probably be confusing.

In C++ the difference becomes useful to the language. You can overload `operator->` for a class type, for example smart pointers do. But class types can have members accessed with `.`. So `some_smart_ptr->get();` means "call the `get()` function on the referand of the smart pointer", whereas `some_smart_ptr.get()` means "call the `get()` function on the smart pointer".

Answer (score 1):

A reference is a basically pointer with a constant address, so it has the same effect as calling by address. It's mainly a difference of syntax: calling by reference is more convenient since from the call site it's as if you were calling by value (except you have to be careful with temporaries).