# C++ copy constructor syntax: Is ampersand reference to r/l values?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, lvalue, ampersand, addressof

The following is an excerpt from my C++ text, illustrating the syntax for declaring a class with a copy constructor.

```
class Student {
     int no;
     char* grade;
 public:
     Student();
     Student(int, const char*);
     Student(const Student&);
     ~Student();
     void display() const; 
 };
```

The copy constructor, as shown here:

```
Student(const Student&);
```

Has an ampersand *after* the parameter Student.

In C, and C++ as-well I believe, the ampersand character is used as a 'address of' operator for pointers. Of course, it is standard to use the & character *before* the pointer name, and the copy constructor uses it after, so I assume this is not the same operator.

Another use of the ampersand character I found, relates to Rvalues and Lvalues as seen here: http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html

My question is not about Rvalues and Lvalues, I just want to know *why* the & character is placed *after* parameter, and what this is called and if/why it is necessary.

Comment: The `&` denotes that this is a *reference* to a `const Student`, not a copy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943276/what-does-do-in-a-c-declaration you can check this link too http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/references.html

Comment: Some maniacs would write this as Student(Student const&)

Comment: @geeksoul - Your second link didn't work.

Comment: @bigcodeszzer, it has moved to https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references

Comment: If you have a C++ text then you should read it.

Comment: @JonathanWakely - See the comments under the accepted answer.

Comment: What the textbook /should/ have said was: Be aware, C++ added another unnecessary feature to over complicate things. They are called 'references' and are pointers that you can't change. To further muddy the already majorly misunderstood concept of pointers, they even used the & operator, (and gotcha! - it has nothing to do with 'address of')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ has reference type that does not exist in C. `&` is used to define such a type.

```
int i = 10;
int& iref = i;
```

Here `iref` is a reference to `i`.

Any changes made to `i` is visible through `iref` and any changes made to `iref` is visible through `i`.

```
iref = 10; // Same as i = 10;
i = 20;    // Same as iref = 20;
```

The reference can be an lvalue reference or an rvalue reference. In the above example, `iref` is an lvalue reference.

```
int&& rref = 10;
```

Here `rref` is an rvalue reference.

You can read more about rvalue references at  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference.

Comment: Is it like a processor command or does it actually take memory? What is the difference between the  int& type and a pointer?

Comment: @bigcodeszzer `int&` is implemented using `int*`, it's masked pointer, you can not change the address of.

Comment: It is not a preprocessor operation. The difference between a pointer and reference is that a pointer can be changed to point to a different object than what it was initialized with. A reference, on the other hand, must be initialized and what it references cannot be changed after that. It's like a pointer that cannot be changed to point to anything else after it's initialized.

Comment: @bigcodeszzer References are mostly used for function arguments, so you can assign to the caller's variable without having to write `&var` when calling and `*ptr` when assigning. It's basically just a convenience feature.

Comment: @bigcodeszzer Isn't all this explained in your textbook? I can't imagine it uses examples without explaining the basics behind them.

Comment: @Barmar It did actually, I must have missed it. But still, it doesn't state it as a data type, it just lumped it under 'pass by reference' which meant something totally different in C.