# How do I iterate over a group of vectors by their references?

Tags: c++

I've got two vectors, and I want to fill both of them from the `cin`. My normal approach here is to create two for loops, but today I've tried to do it like this:

```
vector<long long> a(n);
vector<long long> b(n);

for(auto& vec : {a, b}) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> vec[i];
    }
}
```

With this solution I get a compilation error, telling me that my `vec[i]` is a vector, while I expect it to be a `long long int`:

```
error: no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘std::istream’ {aka ‘std::basic_istream<char>’} and ‘std::vector<long long int>’)
```

I thought that it is some magic which I can't understand and tried to dereference `vec`, but that didn't help either:

```
error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘const std::vector<long long int>’)
   17 |             cin >> (*vec)[i];
      |                     ^~~~
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why isn't `auto&` giving me a pointer, as I expect? How do I make this code work?

Comment: fwiw also in `for (auto& x : a) {..}` there is no pointer, `x` is a reference to elements in `a`

Comment: Why do you expect `auto&` to give you a pointer?

Comment: @idclev463035818 sure, but since I'm iterating over `{a, b}`, I expect it to give me references for vectors `a` and `b`.

Comment: @NotAProgrammer well, & operator [should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943276/what-does-do-in-a-c-declaration) return a pointer to an object (auto, vector<long long> in my case), as far as I know

Comment: There is no `operator&` in your code, you declare a variable of type `auto&` - that is something different

Comment: Interesting. From the message I get with this code, it looks like a `const` issue: `error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}' and 'const value_type {aka const long long int}')`

Comment: I don't know what code you compiled, but your first example (after all *unrelated* issues are fixed manually, post a [mre] when you ask, please) contains an error about `cin` and `const long long int` http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a7b4077579a949f

Comment: Yes you get a reference. In your code you have `cin >> vec[i];`, which is right, but the error message refers to `cin >> (*vec)[i];` which is wrong. The code you show is not the code you've compiled.

Comment: `{a, b}`, in this case, is a `std::initializer_list<std::vector<long long>>` and `std::initializer_list`'s elements are `const`.

Comment: As suggested by somebody out there: this `auto vec : {&a, &b}` with this `cin >> (*vec)[i];` compiles